# Using prepared statements my webpage takes a long time to load

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a webpage that displays 119 rows of model updates. I am using 2 SQL queries on the webpage. The 1st query displays each model update, the 2nd query displays the name or names of each model associated with each particular update. I return the results using each query in a while loop. I am using PHP and Mysqli prepared statements to do so. The page is displaying correctly however it's is taking 15 seconds or so to display the webpage results. It's not an issue with the server as other pages of the site load just fine. The database and the website are on the same server. I'm not sure what I could be doing wrong. Here's the code I used.

Both of these queries are run on the same page and its taking forever for the page to load.

1st query

Query the database for all the updates

```
$sql = "SELECT update_id, title, posted, duration, thumbnail, 
                alt_tag, title_tag, visible
        FROM updates";
$stmt = $conn->stmt_init();
$stmt->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($update_id, $title, $posted, $duration, $thumbnail, $alt_tag, $title_tag, $visible);
$stmt->store_result();
```

2nd query

Query the database for the model names associated with each update

```
$modelNames_sql = "SELECT updates.update_id, models.model_id, 
                        first_name, last_name, updates_models.update_id, 
                        updates_models.model_id
                    FROM updates, models, updates_models
                    WHERE updates.update_id = updates_models.update_id 
                      AND models.model_id = updates_models.model_id 
                      AND updates.update_id = ?";
$stmt2 = $conn->stmt_init();
$stmt2->prepare($modelNames_sql);
$stmt2->bind_param('i', $update_id);
$stmt2->execute();
$stmt2->bind_result($update_id, $model_id, $first_name, $last_name, $update_id, $model_id);
$stmt2->store_result();
```

Comment: Are your tables indexed properly? Have you tested the queries in a stand-alone environment to make sure the queries are the problem?

Comment: Why not make a single query of those 2. Using JOIN as thats basically already what the second query is doing

Comment: Your db engine is? You loop the result of the first query to do the second query? So the total queries are 120?

Comment: Before I used prepared SQL queries, I used standard 2 standard SQL queries and the paged loaded normally. Does that help any?